# Windows 8 / Metro Certification Requirements - How to check?

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

In order to get your application certified for Windows 8, Microsoft says that you need to "only use APIs for Metro Style Apps" ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx))

Is there a tool that can be used to check against existing C++ code to find out if your existing application is in compliance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Windows App Certification Kit (WACK), which is installed as part of the Windows 8 Developer Preview.  You can find instructions for using it on MSDN:

> ["How to test your app with the Windows App Certification Kit"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694081.aspx)

If you want to test existing libraries, you can create a Metro-style app that references those libraries and run WACK on that app.  (Note, if you want to test a static library, you need to exercise enough of its functionality from the app so that all of its functions get linked in.)

Comment: Sure.  I should probably note that you should remember that it's a Developer _Preview_, so some things may change in future releases; some APIs disallowed in the Developer Preview may be allowed later, and some APIs currently allowed may be disallowed.  Everything is subject to change, but what's there in the Developer Preview is a good place to start.